# Как получить входные параметры POST запроса через ActionFilterAttribute, MVC

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь с помощью класса ActionFilterAttribute получить входные параметры POST запроса вот таким способом:

```
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            log.Trace($"Params: {filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString}");
        }
```

Сам запрос:

```html
function GetData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost....",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ value: JSON.stringify("Параметры")}), 
                crossDomain: true,
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
                headers: { User: "User", Password: "Password" },
                success: function (q, w, e) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(q));
                },
                error: function (q, w, e) {
                    alert("Ошибка: " + w);
                }
            });
        }
```

Строка `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString` приходит все время пустой. Пробовал получить входные параметры через  `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream; filterContext.HttpContext.Request.BinaryRead(int);`, но они тоже пустые, хотя запрос отрабатывает и возвращает результат. Может быть, кто-нибудь пользуется фильтрами в MVC и может подсказать, как получить входные параметры запроса в методе `OnActionExecuting` через переменную `filterContext`?

Comment: попробуйте так, value имя параметра- `var param = filterContext.ActionParameters["value"];`

Comment: @Ruslan_K, большое спасибо), работает. Можете как ответ оформить, я проголосую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что мне помогло:

```
    private Dictionary<string, object> parameters;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        parameters = (Dictionary<string, object>)filterContext.ActionParameters;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValue in parameters)
        {
            log.Trace($"Param {count}: (Key: {keyValue.Key}, Value: {keyValue.Value.ToString()})");
            count++;
        }

    }
```

Спасибо Ruslan_K за совет.